# How to use MSAL-React with class component?

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal

Am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react in my react project. The library provides hooks to perform auth very easliy.

So in functional component, for getting access token,

```
if (account && inProgress === "none") {
instance.acquireTokenSilent({
...loginRequest,
account: account
}).then((response) => {
callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
});
}
```

needs to be called where `const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();` is used.

But I need to call api to fetch data from class components.
So, how to achieve the same functionality in class component

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the msal-react hooks inside your class components, so to do this you would either need to [access the raw context](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md#consuming-the-raw-context), or wrap with a [higher order component](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md#wrapping-your-component-with-the-withmsal-higher-order-component).

The following takes the examples from documentation, modified to your question about accessing `instance, accounts, inProgress` for subsequent API calls.

**Consuming Raw Context**

```
import React from "react";
import { MsalContext } from "@azure/msal-react";

class YourClassComponent extends React.Component {
static contextType = MsalContext;

render() {
    const msalInstance = this.context.instance;
    const msalAccounts = this.context.accounts;
    const msalInProgress = this.context.inProgress;
    // rest of your render code
    }
}
```

}

**Using Higher-Order-Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { withMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

class YourClassComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const msalInstance = this.props.msalContext.instance;
        const msalAccounts = this.props.msalContext.accounts;
        const msalInProgress = this.props.msalContext.inProgress;
        // rest of your render code
    }
}

export default YourWrappedComponent = withMsal(YourClassComponent);
```

Either way works so personal preference really. I prefer accessing the raw context over wrapping for readability.